# Node Hover Effect

Tags: matplotlib, pyqt5, python-3.6, networkx

I am trying to display node attributes(E.G.: words) when a mouse is placed over a networkx generated node. Is there a possibility of making that possible. All this feature should be tailored inside a **PyQt5** application.

Example:

```
 #A bit of idea
    for i, elrow in df.iterrows():
        G.add_nodes(elrow[0], elrow[1], attr_dict=elrow[2:].to_dict(), weight=elrow(3)) #Just giving an instance
```

How do i grab all the data in `attr_dict` to be the node properties on hover with a mouse

Comment: Could you explain me better, where do the nodes show? provide a [mcve]

Comment: About the node, they are plotted within a matplotlib canvas and figure. So, i want the nodes to show more information on hover. eg. a, b, c, d, e are the nodes, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 are the edge attributes. I want the node's attributes per pay have this on hover effect.  a: "James", b: "Michael", c: "Peter", d: "Joel", e: "Smith". all this names are what i want displayed. Can't give image example cause i don't know how

Comment: provide a MCVE....

Answer (score -1):

You should use [bokeh](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) library for this kind of visualization.

You can find an exact solution for your problem [here](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/graph.html#node-and-edge-attributes):

```
import networkx as nx

from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import Plot, Range1d, MultiLine, Circle, HoverTool, BoxZoomTool, ResetTool
from bokeh.models.graphs import from_networkx
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral4

# Prepare Data
G = nx.karate_club_graph()

SAME_CLUB_COLOR, DIFFERENT_CLUB_COLOR = "black", "red"
edge_attrs = {}

for start_node, end_node, _ in G.edges(data=True):
    edge_color = SAME_CLUB_COLOR if G.nodes[start_node]["club"] == G.nodes[end_node]["club"] else DIFFERENT_CLUB_COLOR
    edge_attrs[(start_node, end_node)] = edge_color

nx.set_edge_attributes(G, edge_attrs, "edge_color")

# Show with Bokeh
plot = Plot(plot_width=400, plot_height=400,
            x_range=Range1d(-1.1, 1.1), y_range=Range1d(-1.1, 1.1))
plot.title.text = "Graph Interaction Demonstration"

node_hover_tool = HoverTool(tooltips=[("index", "@index"), ("club", "@club")])
plot.add_tools(node_hover_tool, BoxZoomTool(), ResetTool())

graph_renderer = from_networkx(G, nx.spring_layout, scale=1, center=(0, 0))

graph_renderer.node_renderer.glyph = Circle(size=15, fill_color=Spectral4[0])
graph_renderer.edge_renderer.glyph = MultiLine(line_color="edge_color", line_alpha=0.8, line_width=1)
plot.renderers.append(graph_renderer)

output_file("interactive_graphs.html")
show(plot)
```

Comment: How can i implement this to a PyQt5 application? Everything is going to be displayed on a matplotlib canvas which has a figure space attached to it.

Comment: Bokeh returns an HTML snippet. You can visualize it with QWebEngine.

Comment: This is gonna be hard to implement with the way this is going. I already have an application GUI flow and would not want to change that for implementing a bokeh feature. I have it on Github if you think you can find work through??

Comment: QWebView widget will help you - you can send Bokeh-generated HTML into it and visualize within an application. I worked only with Qt, not with PyQt so I can't help you how to do it inside the Python code. But in C++ Qt it should work.

Comment: Just read on QWebView for python and am seeing that there is an issue with support for showing the bokeh generated HTML. That aside, have you ever come across the ability to change arrows direction from one node to another and that automatically reflects in the spreadsheet that initially generated the graph

Comment: There is no simple way to do it in Python. You are trying to re-implement the new Gephi or yEd. You will have to do most of your work by yourself.

Comment: I figured that much will have to skip that implementation actually for the last. Focus on the rest functionalities like adding activity dependencies(SS, SF, FS, FF) which no youtube video is popping out to learn from.